# uploading a file into google drive

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file into my drive but the response is always null

i created a developer account then i got my api key and my client secret and id
but i still think that the problem is in the authentication step

```
   static string ApplicationName = "WebApi";
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
     new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
     {
         ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
         {
             ClientId = "my_client_ID",
             ClientSecret = "my_client_secret",

         },
         Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts},
         DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
     });


      public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var service = new DriveService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "my_api_key",
            HttpClientInitializer = flow as UserCredential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });

        insertFile(service, "file_name.mdf", "", "", "application/octet-stream", "file_name.mdf");

    }



       private static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File insertFile(DriveService service, String title, String description, String parentId, String mimeType, String filename)
    {

        // File's metadata
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new 
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = title;
        body.Description = description;
        body.MimeType = mimeType;
        body.Parents = body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>();

        // Set the parent folder.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId))
        {
            body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>()
      {new ParentReference() {Id = parentId}};
        }

        // File's content.
        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        try
        {
            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream,mimeType );
            request.Upload();

            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;

            // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);

            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {    
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

i am creating the service in the main window the i am trying to insert
the file in the insert file function

i am getting a null response please help..

Comment: Have you tried inserting checkers just to see where it actually encounters a problem?